Why did the log record is normal, but Apache IoTDB is still unable to connect in host mode of docker network?
I use the host mode in docker network to build 1 ConfigNode and 1 DataNode system of Apache IoTDB. The log record is in in normal startup status (mentioned that the DataNodes are all set up), but the system is still unable to connect. My configurations are as follows: cn_internal_address=127.0.0.1, cn_seed_config_node-192.168.111.24:10710, cn_internal_port=10710, cn_consensus_port=10720, dn_mpp_data_exchange_port=10740, dn_schema_region_consensus port=10750, dn_data _region_consensus_port=10760. Has anyone encountered this problem and how to solve it?

You can check if you can connect Apache IoTDB through container. If you can, then you can change the 127 port to 192 to expose the port routine, and you can connect directly (not through container).
